# Reading unsingned chars with Qt

Tags: file, qt, binary

Hi fellow stack overflowers,

I'm currently parsing a file which both contains text and binary data. Currently, I'm reading the file in following manner:

```
QTextStream in(&file);

int index = 0;
while(!in.atEnd()) {
    if (index==0) {
        QString line = in.readLine(); // parse file here
    } else {
        QByteArray raw_data(in.readAll().toAscii());
        data = new QByteArray(raw_data);
    }
    index++;
}
```

where data refers to the binary data I'm looking for. I'm not sure if this is what I want, since the QString is encoded into ascii and I have no idea if some bytes are lost.

I checked the documentation, and it recommends using a QDataStream. How can I combine both approaches, i.e. read lines with an encoding and also read the binary dump, after one line break?

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you want.

```
QTextStream t(&in);
QString line;
QByteArray raw_data;
if(!in.atEnd()) {line = t.readLine();}
in.reset();
int lineSize = line.toLocal8Bit().size() + 1;
in.seek(lineSize);
if(!in.atEnd())
{
    int len = in.size() - lineSize;
    QDataStream d(&in);
    char *raw = new char[len]();
    d.readRawData(raw, len);
    raw_data = QByteArray(raw, len);
    delete raw;
}
```

PS: if file format is yours, it will be better to create file with QDataStream and write data with `<<`, read with `>>`. This way you can store `QByteArray` and `QString` in file without such problems.

Comment: The above code contains errors: calling in.size() is not possible since QTextStream doesn't offer said method. Also the conversion: QDataStream d(&in); also results in an error.

Comment: `in` is not `QTextStream`, `in` is a `QFile`. `QTextStream t`
(in my code sample)

Comment: okay, thanks!. Assumed you used my variable names. It seems to work now. Thanks!

Comment: do you have any idea if there's a difference in saving unsigned chars as opposed to chars in a QByteArray?

Comment: Why do you reset? Attaching the QDataStream should pick up where the QTextStream left off.

Comment: @Phlucious It seems, that you must reset the stream manually.

Comment: @Phlucious, after reading from `QTextStream` `QFile::atEnd()` returns `true as well as `QDataStream::atEnd()`, so I manually reset and seek file.

Comment: @anopheles `QByteArray` seems more appritiate way of storing data in qT. From the docs:
**Using QByteArray is much more convenient than using const char *. Behind the scenes, it always ensures that the data is followed by a '\0' terminator, and uses implicit sharing (copy-on-write) to reduce memory usage and avoid needless copying of data.**

Comment: @DmitryMelnikov: I'm currently using QByteArray, but I later have to pass the data to a function that expects it to be an array of unsingned char